# Add a droplist menu to a list item CSS

Tags: html, css

I wanted to add a droplist to the 4th element in my navbar .
Under "ESPACE PARTICULIER" I need to get 2 options .

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">A PROPOS NOUS</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">COURS</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">SERVICES</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">ESPACE PARTICULIER</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="button-highlight" href="#">Sign in</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using Bootstrap so it's easy to do it Jus take alook in this [Bootstrap Dropdown](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/)

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">A PROPOS NOUS</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">COURS</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">SERVICES</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown"role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">ESPACE PARTICULIER</a>
            
           <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>

        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="button-highlight" href="#">Sign in</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the [manual](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/)

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">A PROPOS NOUS</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">COURS</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">SERVICES</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">ESPACE PARTICULIER</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```